# Hasura Migration failed : Required privilege is not held by client

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura, database-metadata

I'm trying to apply migration, I'm able to successfully execute following command

> hasura migrate apply --endpoint http://192.168.99.100:8080/

but when I try to execute next command, I get below mentioned error,, any idea ...

> hasura metadata apply --endpoint http://192.168.99.100:8080/

```
INFO unable to install cli-ext plugin. execute the following commands to continu
e:

  hasura plugins install cli-ext
time="2020-06-16T01:31:18+04:00" level=fatal msg="failed to apply metadata: cann
ot apply metadata on the database: cannot build actions from metadata: cannot in
stall plugin cli-ext: install failed: failed to link installed plugin: failed to
 create a symlink from \"C:\\\\Users\\\\umar.farooq\\\\.hasura\\\\plugins\\\\sto
re\\\\cli-ext\\\\v1.2.2\\\\cli-ext-hasura-win.exe\" to \"C:\\\\Users\\\\umar.far
ooq\\\\.hasura\\\\plugins\\\\bin\\\\hasura-cli_ext.exe\": symlink C:\\Users\\uma
r.farooq\\.hasura\\plugins\\store\\cli-ext\\v1.2.2\\cli-ext-hasura-win.exe C:\\U
sers\\umar.farooq\\.hasura\\plugins\\bin\\hasura-cli_ext.exe: A required privile
ge is not held by the client."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open command line as *administrator* and retry the migrations.
For reference: https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4852

Comment: thanks it worked. it needs to be updated in hasura official docs as well.

Answer (score 0):

run this as sudo before retry the migration (as non sudo):

```sh
sudo hasura plugins install cli-ext
```

then

```sh
hasura migrate apply --endpoint http://192.168.99.100:8080/
```